# If 4 Unitary maps amount to the identity, whats the general relationship between them?

Tags: group-theory, linear-transformations, group-actions, unitary-matrices

Say we play a game where we pick a random point $\rho \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$.
The rules are, you can pick any 4 unitary $(\mathcal{U}:\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}) \rightarrow \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}))$ maps $\mathcal{U}_1, \mathcal{U}_2, \mathcal{U}_3$, and $\mathcal{U}_4$ to apply onto the state, such that their joint action amounts to the identity:

$(\mathcal{U}_4 \circ \mathcal{U}_3 \circ \mathcal{U}_2 \circ \mathcal{U}_1)[\rho] = \mathcal{I}[\rho]=\rho$,

and $\mathcal{U}_i \mathcal{U}_i^{\dagger} = \mathcal{U}_i^{\dagger} \mathcal{U}_i = \mathcal{I}$.

Is there an elegant way to find all the "strategies" which make this work?
Or alternatively, what's the general relationship between these 4 maps such that the above is true.

### My thoughts

By the power of associativity and the unitary condition above, there's a few obvious strategies which work.

1. Pick three random rotations $\mathcal{U}_1, \mathcal{U}_2, \mathcal{U}_3$, and make the 4th the $\dagger$ of the first three: $\mathcal{U}_4 = (\mathcal{U}_1 \circ \mathcal{U}_2 \circ \mathcal{U}_3)^{\dagger}$. The same works if the first unitary is the $\dagger$ of the last three too.
2. Pick two random rotations and make the remaining two be the $\dagger$'s of each of them e.g. $\mathcal{U}_2 = \mathcal{U}_1^{\dagger}$ and $\mathcal{U}_4 = \mathcal{U}_3^{\dagger}$. This works in any order.
3. Pick 4 unitaries that amount to a $2\pi$ rotation in a plane.

Those are the obvious ones. But what about a general statement where this is true? Is there a framework where this question becomes simple to answer? The tags show my guesses, but I'd be open to anything.

Comment: But why 4? Is the answer for 3 kind of obvious? Because if you have answer for 3 it would go a long way to solving the problem.

Comment: Why 4? Well, that's what the game I'm playing requires haha! But you make a good point. Let's see, if there's 2 then the only strategies are (1) Pick any rotation, choose the other to be the $\dagger$ of it, and (2) Pick two unitaries that rotate by $\pi$ in the same plane. Am I missing any there?